# memcached php on lampp

Tags: php, linux, lampp

i have trouble with installing memcached php on lampp in linux distribution MINT 15, i searched all over the internet, including stackoverflow, i tried install and failed, because when i start command in terminal

```
/etc/init.d/memcached start

Starting memcached: "memcached.
```

but it doesn't work because i still get error in php code.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Memcached extension failed to load.' in ...

any help?!

Comment: Your PHP does not have ``memcached`` extension. Note that it's different from ``memcache`` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have compatible with your OS:

- libevent API
- memcache php module
- memcached